# The base of an isosceles triangle; given the radius of the inscribed circle and perimeter

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

> On the sketch below $AC=CB$ and $OD=\dfrac{4}{10}CD$. If the perimeter of $\triangle ABC$ is $P_{\triangle ABC}=40$, find the length of the base $AB$.

[image]

Let $AC=BC=a$ and $AB=c$. Since the triangle is isosceles, $CD$ is also the altitude and the median. So we have $AD=BD=\dfrac12c$. How should I use the fact that $CD=\dfrac{4}{10}CD$? Thank you in advance! Any help would be appreciated.

*I have not studied trigonometry.*

Comment: You seem to have ignored the fact that the circle centered at $O$ is inscribed in $ABC$. Without that fact there is no way to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the radius from $O$ to $AC$ at $P$.  Triangles $ADC$ and $OPC$ are similar and $OP = OD$.  Enough?

EDIT:  Let the height $CD=h.$  Then $OD = .4h$ and so $CO = .6h.$  You have

$$\frac{2}{3} = \frac{.4h}{.6h} = \frac{OP}{OC} = \frac{AD}{AC} =\frac{c}{2a}.$$

Now use that the perimeter is $40.$

Comment: Thank you for the response! I appreciate it. Okay! Triangles $ADC$ and $OPC$ are similar because $\measuredangle ADC=\measuredangle CPO=90^\circ$ and they share angle $C$. Therefore, $\dfrac{AD}{OP}=\dfrac{CD}{CP}=\dfrac{AC}{CO}$. How to use this to find $AB$?

Comment: I don't know why I can't tag you. I am sorry.

Comment: See edits.  I would automatically get a ping when someone responds to my answer, so there's no need to tag me.

Comment: Oh, okay! I didn't know that! You forgot to add the zeros.

Comment: $\dfrac{AD}{AC}=\dfrac{c}{2a}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $|AB|=c$,
$|CD|=h_c$,
$|OD|=r=\tfrac2{5}\,h_c$,
$\rho=\tfrac12\,P=20$. 
Then
using the formula for the area,
\begin{align} 
S_{ABC}&=\tfrac12\,c\,h_c
,\\
c&=
\frac{2\,S_{ABC}}{h_c}
=
\frac{2\rho\,r}{h_c}
=
\frac{2\rho\,\tfrac25\,h_c}{h_c}
=
\tfrac45\rho
=16
.
\end{align}